# Search and replace entire directory file contents

Tags: php, replace

I need to re-write multiple files in a single directory based on the contents of a single CSV file.

For example the CSV file would contain something like this:

```
define("LANG_BLABLA", "NEW");
```

In one of the files in the directory it would contain this:

```
define("LANG_BLABLA", "OLD");
```

The script will search through the directory and any occurrences where the CSV "LANG_BLABLA" matches the old directory LANG it will update the "OLD" with the "NEW"

My question is how exactly can I list the contents of the files in the directory in 1 array so I can easily search through them and replace where necessary.

Thanks.

Comment: Are you sure it's a CSV file and not a PHP file of `define`s?

Comment: You don't "list" the contents of the files. Do you want to know how to list the files in a directory (recursively?), or how to read/replace/save a file given its full path?

Comment: I can't imagine any reason why this would be a good solution to your problem and your eaxmple would not be valid csv, also how would it know what to replace with what ?

Comment: Effectively the script will be running through each file in the directory and it will replace the old define with the new(located in the csv).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Searching through a directory is relatively easy:

```
<?
clearstatcache();
$folder  = "C:/web/website.com/some/folder";
$objects = scandir($folder, SCANDIR_SORT_NONE);
foreach ($objects as $obj) {
    if ($obj === '.' || $obj === '..')
        continue; // current and parent dirs
    $path = "{$folder}/{$obj}";
    if (strcasecmp(substr($path, -4), '.php') !== 0)
        continue // Not a PHP file
    if (is_link($path))
        $path = realpath($path);
    if ( ! is_file($path))
        continue; // Not a file, probably a folder
    $data = file_get_contents($path);
    if ($data === false)
        die('Some error occured...')
    // ...
    // Do your magic here
    // ...
    if (file_put_contents($path, $data) === false)
        die('Failed to write file...');
}
```

As for modifying PHP files dynamically, it is probably a sign that you need to put that stuff into a database or in-memory data-store... MySQL, SQLite, MongoDB, memcached, Redis, etc. should do. Which you should use would depend on the nature of your project.

Answer (score 0):

You can parse a CSV file into an array using `fgetcsv` http://php.net/manual/en/function.fgetcsv.php

Comment: Parsing the CSV isn't the issue, the problem is parsing the contents of all the files in the directory so the script can look up and replace any LANG_ that exists in both

Comment: If you parse all of the files into different arrays then you can compare them.

Comment: That's the method I was looking to avoid as there is about 50+ files in the directory

Answer (score 0):

First of all I would not recommend this workflow if you working with .php files. Try to centralize your define statements and then change it in a single location.

But here is a solution that should work for you csv files. It's not complete, you have to add some of your desired logic.

```
/**
 * Will return an array with key value coding of your csv
 * @param $defineFile Your file which contains multiple definitions e.g. define("LANG_BLABLA", "NEW");\n define("LANG_ROFL", "LOL");
 * @return array
 */
public function getKeyValueArray($defineFile)
{
    if (!file_exists($defineFile)) {
        return array();
    } else {
        $fp = @fopen($defineFile, 'r');
        $values = explode("\n", fread($fp, filesize($defineFile)));
        $newValues = array();
        foreach ($values as $val) {
            preg_match("%.*\"(.*)?\",\s+\"(.*)?\".*%", $val, $matches);
            $newValues[$matches[1]] = $matches[2];
        }
    }
}
/**
* This is s stub! You should implement the rest yourself.
*/
public function updateThings()
    {
        //Read your definition into an array
        $defs=$this->getKeyValueArray("/some/path/to/your/file");
        $scanDir="/your/desired/path/with/input/files/";
        $otherFiles= scandir($scanDir);
        foreach($otherFiles as $file){
            if($file!="." && $file!=".."){
                //read in the file definition
                $oldDefinitionArray=$this->getKeyValueArray($scanDir.$file);
                //Now you have your old file in an array e.g. array("LANG_BLABLA" => "OLD")
                //and you already have your new file in $defs
                //You now loop over both and check for each key in $defs
                //if its value equals the value in the $oldDefinitionArray.
                //You then update your csv or rewrite or do whatever you like.
            }
        }
    }
```